# Rails Internationalization: Setting the Locale from the Domain Name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, internationalization

I'm trying to implement internationalization on my rails app. Here's part of my application controller

```
before_action :set_locale

def set_locale
  I18n.locale = extract_locale_from_tld || I18n.default_locale
end

def extract_locale_from_tld
  parsed_locale = request.host.split('.').last
  I18n.available_locales.include?(parsed_locale.to_sym) ? parsed_locale  : nil
end
```

It seems not to work and I can only set the locale from url params making me use `scope "(:locale)", locale: /en|se/ do` in my routes which I don't want to.

From the rails guide, they point out that the switching menu should be implemented like this.

```
link_to("Deutsch", "#{APP_CONFIG[:deutsch_website_url]}#{request.env['REQUEST_URI']}")
```

how do you implement this? 
My current switching menu looks like this.

```
<% if I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale %>
   <li><%= link_to image_tag("eng.png", :alt => "England", :class =>"round"), :locale=>'en' %>
   <li><h5><%= link_to_unless I18n.locale == :se, "Swedish", "#{'http://www.natkurser.se'}" %></h5>  
<% else %>
   <li><%= link_to image_tag("swe.png", :alt => "Sweden", :class =>"round"), :locale=>'se' %>
   <li><h5><%= link_to_unless I18n.locale == :en, "English", "#{'http://gettheskill.com'}" %></h5>  
<%end%>
```

I've added 127.0.0.1 gettheskill.com and 127.0.0.1 natkuser.se to /etc/hosts but it still doesn't work on developement. What file(s) do I modify so that it works on production? I'm thinking nginx configuration files. And ultimately, how is the routes supposed to appear. This is the main thing that seems to have been left out in rails internationalization documentation. A detailed answer would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your question is not very structured, i will try giving some hints never the less.

if you want to have a look at a working example for locales and domains have a look at [the onruby project](https://github.com/phoet/on_ruby). it's a multitenant application where each tenant can configure his own domains and default locales.

this is the way that it is implemented:

the site uses a cookie to track the currently selected locale.

if no cookie is set, it uses the domain name to resolve it. to test that in development, you will have to use `/etc/hosts` and add the domains in there, so that they can get resolved locally. in your case this would be gettheskill.com:3000 to access your app.

i usually use a slightly different domain name, either appending a subdomain or a different tld, so that i can still access the domains over the internet without editing `/etc/hosts`.

the language switches work simply by appending the parameter `locale=XY` to a link. so `params[:locale]` always takes precedence and switches the selected locale and sets a new value to the cookie.

i hope this is enough information to get it working for you.

and NO, there is nothing that has to be configured outside of rails or the `/etc/hosts` file.

Comment: thanks for the post. Here's the thing though, I'm having the problem with switching the locale. The site's default locale is in english, I need it to change to Swedish when I click on the link on switching menu. Now it worked with scope (:locale) /en|se on routes but after I removed it, it's not. I had to remove the scope because I wanted to implement i18n from domain name. I hope you're getting my point.

Answer (score 2):

I have followed the rails guide and have setup the i18n accordingly. I couldn't understand your problem. The only thing difference I had was the extraction of locale. Instead of the last, I used request.subdomains.first .

```
def extract_locale_from_subdomain
  parsed_locale = request.subdomains.first
  I18n.available_locales.include?(parsed_locale.to_sym) ? parsed_locale : nil
end
```

Did you set up your load paths as told in rails guide.

```
# in config/initializers/locale.rb

# tell the I18n library where to find your translations
I18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('lib', 'locale', '*.{rb,yml}')]

# set default locale to something other than :en
I18n.default_locale = :en
```

And check what **I18n.available_locales** returns, nil or locales. And the switching menu you are using seems fine. It would work that way also.

If you could explain your problem more specifically, maybe I could help.
Thanks.

EDIT:

This would be suffice for your view to have a switch language link.

```
<% if I18n.locale == I18n.default_locale %>
   <li><%= link_to image_tag("swe.png", :alt => "Sweden", :class =>"round"), "http://www.natkurser.se" %>  %>
   <li><h5><%= link_to_unless I18n.locale == :se, "Swedish", "#{'http://www.natkurser.se'}" %></h5>  
<% else %>
   <li><%= link_to image_tag("eng.png", :alt => "England", :class =>"round"), "http://gettheskill.com" %>
   <li><h5><%= link_to_unless I18n.locale == :en, "English", "#{'http://gettheskill.com'}" %></h5>  
<%end%>
```

Comment: I've implemented all that you've said. Problem is that the switching menu seems not to be working. The default locale is english so thing is I need the site to change to Swedish when I click on the switching link.

Comment: Did you try removing the image_tag and checked if it works only with the link_to_unless part?

Comment: <%= link_to image_tag("eng.png", :alt => "England", :class =>"round"), "#{'http://www.natkurser.se'}" %>

Comment: Try this for your image tag. Replace the link with relevant information<%= link_to image_tag("swe.png", :alt => "Sweden", :class =>"round"), "#{'http://www.natkurser.se'}" %>

Comment: thanks a lot. It's now working. But here's a quick question before you go, how will the configurations for the two urls in production be? Or rather how should I go about it?

Comment: @the Areba Good to hear it helped. I think it wont make any fuss over the production environment. Anyway you can make sure by running the server in production mode. If this solved your problem, please accept by clicking the check mark.